# Symfony2: Money field type invalid input error

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, money-format

I've some weird Symfony2 behaviour I don't understand. Let's say there is an entity Product:

```
class Product
{
    /** Some doctrine things */
    protected $id;

    /** Some doctrine things */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="This field cannot be empty.")
     * @Assert\GreaterThan(value=0, message="Please enter an amount higher than 0.")
     */
    private $price;

    /** Getters and setters */
}
```

To add a product I'm using a form ProductType, using this form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('price', 'money', array('currency' => false, 'invalid_message' => 'Please enter a valid value.'))
}
```

Everything is working fine, except when I submit some invalid values:

- **1foo** generates 'Please enter a valid value.', as expected
- **foo1** generates an Internal Server Error: 'Warning: NumberFormatter::parse(): Number parsing failed'
- **foo** generates an Internal Server Error: 'Warning: NumberFormatter::parse(): Number parsing failed'

I'm using SF2 v2.6 on a local WampServer.

Comment: I'm using SF2 v2.6 and I cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: Thanks for trying, I'm using SF2 v2.6 as well, on a local WampServer. I edited my OP with this information, maybe the issue has something to do with my WampServer settings...

Answer (score 1):

You have `$price` in your entity and `costs` in your form type.

And I guess that `foo1` and `foo` are converted to null. So you can catch this in you setter or use for example a Regex assertion.

Comment: Thanks for noticing! In my attempt to simplify the issue I forgot to change the form type.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem also with Symfony 2.6 and Wampserver.

I temporary solved it by disabling the php_intl extension in the php.ini. Then the Assert\Type(type="decimal") seems to become obsolete since it automatically validates against a digit format. Hence all you need is to set a "invalid_message" options on your Formtype field.

Hope this helps.